# Flexbox: Equal Height Rows?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two boxes side by side that contain a title, an image, a line of meta info, and a short paragraph. The image and additional info will always be the same size, but the length of the title and paragraph can differ greatly. Approximate structure:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.col-md-6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="title">
        <h2>Any length of title...</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="#">
      </div>
      <div class="meta">
        <p>Same info here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum et cetera...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a variety of different CSS and I've got it almost working in one instance (https://codepen.io/nickfindley/pen/WPxWNJ) and not at all in another (https://codepen.io/nickfindley/pen/GzbbOQ). I think flexbox is the answer, but I think I don't understand `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, or `flex-basis` well enough to make it work. Am I barking up the right tree or do I need a different solution?

Comment: I don't think it has to do a lot with flex-box. If u give the wrapping container a fixed height, it won't be dependent on the content anymore

Comment: Do you have any ability to change the HTML structure?

Comment: Are you referring to a like cross-browser issue? Because it looks as expected in latest chrome. If it's a cross-browser thing try adding `min-height: 1px` to `.col-md-6` (worth a google as to why that's a thing).

Comment: If you want fix height for three sections, then with flexbox it will be tricky.
Reason being `flex` initially decides the size according the to the properties i.e grow, shrink and basis. But the size is also dependent upon the content it holds.

So if your content surpasses the basis that you have applied, it will expand in size. And that is what you are facing.

You would have to explicitly set the height of each section to achieve equal height rows

Comment: @BryceHowitson I can change the HTML by adding container divs, for example, but the overall document structure needs to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.flex-container {
display: flex;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;

flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-flow: row;
justify-content: space-evenly;

padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
text-align: center;

.row {
position: relative;
}
```

Do this for both boxes and play with the margin and padding (of the .row class) to get it right. I have done something like this earlier and this should work.